# jQuery DataTable copy is not accepting input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am exporting table values in Excel, PDF, Copy but unfortunately my input value is missing in that I could not able to add last updated input value while exporting.

```js
JTable() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    data_table = $('#transaction_items').DataTable({
      dom: `<'row'<'col-sm-6 text-left'f><'col-sm-6 text-right'B>>
        <'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>
        <'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager'lp>>`,
      "columnDefs": [{
        "type": "num-fmt",
        "targets": 5,
        "className": "text-right"
      }],
      paging: false,
      "scrollX": true,
      scrollY: 400,
      scrollCollapse: true,
      info: false,
      // searching: false,
      // sorting:true,
      destroy: true,
      ordering: false,

      buttons: [{
          extend: 'print',
          title: 'Transaction Items',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
          },

        },
        {
          extend: 'excel',
          title: 'Transaction Items',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
          }
        },
        {
          extend: 'copy',
          title: 'Transaction Items',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
          },
          customize: function(doc) {
            console.log("Doc ", doc)
          }
        },
        {
          extend: 'pdf',
          title: 'Transaction Items',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
          }
        }
      ],
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kt-portlet__body">
  <div class="mat-table__wrapper table-responsive" style="overflow-x: auto">
    <table class="table table-striped- table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" style="overflow-x: auto" id="transaction_items">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:center">
          <th>Item Code</th>
          <th>Display Name</th>
          <th>Remarks</th>
          <th>Grower Code</th>
          <th>UoM</th>
          <th>Available Qty</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Unit Price</th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
          <th>Shipment Arrival Date</th>
          <th>Alternative Description</th>
          <th>Delivery Date</th>
          <th>Delivery time</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of addedItem; let i = index">
          <td style="vertical-align: middle" [ngClass]="{highlight: item.BaseUnitPrice < item.PriceListBaseUnitPrice}">{{item.ItemCode}}</td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle" [ngClass]="{highlight: item.BaseUnitPrice < item.PriceListBaseUnitPrice}">
            <div style="width:250px !important;">{{item.DisplayName}}</div>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle">
            <span *ngIf="!editable">{{item.Remarks}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="editable">
                      <input type="text" (input)="item.Remarks = $event.target.value" [value]="item.Remarks"
                        placeholder="Remarks">
                    </span>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle" [ngClass]="{highlight: item.BaseUnitPrice < item.PriceListBaseUnitPrice}">{{item.GrowerCode}}
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle" [ngClass]="{highlight: item.BaseUnitPrice < item.PriceListBaseUnitPrice}">
            {{item.BaseUoMCode ? item.BaseUoMCode : ''}}</td>
          <td style="text-align: right;vertical-align: middle" [ngClass]="{highlight: item.BaseUnitPrice < item.PriceListBaseUnitPrice}">
            {{item.AvailableBaseUnits ? item.AvailableBaseUnits : ''}}</td>
          <td style="text-align: right;vertical-align: middle" [ngClass]="{highlight: item.BaseUnitPrice < item.PriceListBaseUnitPrice}">
            <span *ngIf="!editable">{{item.BaseQuantity}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="editable">
                      <input type="number" onclick="select()" style="width: 50px;text-align: right;"
                        [value]="item.BaseQuantity" (input)="item.BaseQuantity = $event.target.value"
                        (blur)="allowQty(item,$event)" placeholder="Base Quantity" (focus)="focusIn()"
                        (focusout)="getfocusOut()" autocomplete="off" />
                    </span>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: right;vertical-align: middle" [ngClass]="{highlight: item.BaseUnitPrice < item.PriceListBaseUnitPrice}">
            <span *ngIf="!editable">{{getUnitPrice(item.BaseUnitPrice)}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="editable">
                      <input onclick="select()" style="width: 50px;text-align: right;" type="number"
                      (input)="decimalCheck(item, $event)" [value]="getUnitPrice(item.BaseUnitPrice)"
                        (focus)="focusIn()" (focusout)="getfocusOut()" #bsUnprc (blur)="allowLesserPrc(item,
$event)" autocomplete="off"> {{getLineTotal(item.BaseQuantity,item.BaseUnitPrice)}} {{item.ShipmentArrivalDate | date}} {{item.AlternativeDescription}} -Select- {{tax}} {{item.DeliveryDate | date}} {{item.DeliveryTime}}
```

Comment: Have you explored doing this without jQuery, and fully harnessing the power of Angular? Trying to mix the 2 is asking for trouble.

Comment: Can you post your whole angular component? Also, as said before, why would you use jQuery, if you have angular?

Comment: for that Export options like PDF, COPY,EXCEL and PRINT. like this options we can use through angular?